# Replacing strings in file using different values to replace the same pattern

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, sed

I have such strings in my `/etc/mail/virtusertable`

```
mail1@example.com    error:nouser Account temporary disabled
mail2@example.com    error:nouser Account temporary disabled
mail3@example.com    error:nouser Account temporary disabled
```

And I want to replace all `error:nouser Account temporary disabled` with appropriate `virtuser_NNN` which I can get from `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd`

I tried different variants but all with the same result. All `error:nouser Account temporary disabled` replaced with first `virtuser_NNN` from `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd`

After running my script it looks like

```
mail1@example.com    virtuser_1
mail2@example.com    virtuser_1
mail3@example.com    virtuser_1
```

My script is:

```
 cat /etc/mail/virtusertable_back | grep example.com |
 grep 'error:nouser Account temporary disabled' | awk '{print $1}' |
 xargs -I{} grep {} /etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd | awk -F'::' '{print $2}' |
 xargs -I{} sh -c 'grep {} /etc/passwd' | awk -F: '{print $1}'|
 xargs -n1 -P1 -I{} sed -i 's/error\:nouser Account temporary disabled/{}/' /etc/mail/virtusertable_back
```

Yes, I'm doing this on the copy of `/etc/mail/virtusertable`.

And `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd` has records in such format:

```
mail@example.com:*$1$hash here:user id:group id::/var/www/userlogin/data/email/example.com/mail:::/var/mail/virtuser_NNNN
```

Need to add, that I want to change strings with err message to appropriate virtusers only for specific mail domain, not the to the whole file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an excerpt of your `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd` file. I am guessing that it has an email as the first field and a username as the second, is that correct?

Comment: I've updated my question with info about strings format in my `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd`

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in Perl. Save the email and associated username from the `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd` in a hash and then replace in `/etc/mail/virtusertable`:

```
$ perl -i -ape 'BEGIN{
                   open($fh,"/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd");
                    while(<$fh>){ @G=split(/:/); $k{$G[0]}=$G[2]; }
            }
            s/error:nouser Account temporary disabled/$k{$F[0]}/ if defined $k{$F[0]};
'  /etc/mail/virtusertable > newfile
```

#### Explanation

The `-i` makes perl edit its input file in place, same as `sed -i`. The `-a` makes it split each input line on whitespace into the array `@F`. Just like `awk`. The `-p` means "print every line after applying the script given by `-e`".

The script itself reads `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd` in the `BEGIN{}` block (so before reading the input file, `/etc/mail/virtusertable`), splits each line on `:` into the `@G` array and then saves each email as a key in the hash `%k` whose values are the user names.

Once that is finished, it moves on to process `/etc/mail/virtusertable` and replaces each `error:nouser Account temporary disabled` with the user name corresponding to the email on the 1st field if that user name is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The following pipeline should work well provided there are no backslashes in *virtuser_NNN* names:

```
tbl=/etc/mail/virtusertable
pw=/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd
cut  -d:  -f1 "$pw" |  
grep -Fnf-    "$tbl"|
sed  -e's|:.*/\(.*\)|s/:nouser/:\1/|' | 
sed  -f-      "$tbl"
```

It will:

- first `cut` away all but the first sequence of any not-colon characters for each line of *`dovecot.passwd`*
- `grep` for `-F`ixed-string matches to the results in *`virtusertable`*
- `s///`ubstitute away all but the line-number and the last occurring not-slash sequence of characters from those results into a string like:

  - *`[LINENO]`*`s/:nouser/:`*`not-slashes`*`/`
- finally use *that* output as a `sed` script against *`virtusertable`*

Comment: Nice solution to replace strings in whole file, but what I actually need is to replace err messages only for specific domain. I've updated my question with this detail.

Comment: @Nokse - you mean you want to replace *nouser*?

Comment: I mean, that there are lots of correct lines like:
`some_user@example.com       virtuser_3587`
but also there present lines like I mentioned before:
`mail3@example.com    error:nouser Account temporary disabled`
for different mailboxes on different domains. And I want to replace this `error:nouser Account temporary disabled` with correct `virtuser_"number"` only for specific domain. Hope now its clear

Comment: @Nokse - not really clear to me. the best way to get your point across is to edit your question with actual examples of input -> output. if there are some lines in a file which you don't want affected, include some lines like those in your example and specify what it is about them that shouldn't be changed. be clear about what it is that needs changing, and from what source and under what conditions the change ought to be had.